# Android Intent after onpostexecute fails to start

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a registration system. The registration is working fine. My main problem is: I would like to start MainActivity.java after logging in. After sending the login data to the Server, the Server checks in Database if it matches and sends out an int (0 for unmatched) and (1 for success). This works great as well. But if i want to start the Intent after onPostExecute Method it gives out an Error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult
>   ...

This is my StartPage which exectues my AsyncTask Class. And receives success or unmatched in the Method getLoginMessage().

```
public class LoginPage extends Activity {

String userName;
String password;
String sendProtocolToServer;
static String matched = null;
static String unmatched;
static Context myCtx;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginpage);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            handleLogin();
        }
    });

    Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent openMainActivityRegister = new Intent(
                    "com.example.fotosharing.REGISTERPAGE");
            startActivity(openMainActivityRegister);
        }
    });

}

private void handleLogin() {

    EditText editTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextUser);
    EditText passwordTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextPassword);
    userName = editTextBox.getText().toString();
    password = passwordTextBox.getText().toString();

    if (!userName.equals("") && !password.equals("")) {
        sendProtocolToServer = "login" + "#" + userName + "#" + password;
        ConnectToServer cts = new ConnectToServer(sendProtocolToServer);

        cts.execute();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fill in Username and Password to login",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

public void getLoginMessage(String receivedMessage) {

    if (receivedMessage.equals("success")) {
        Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(
                "com.example.fotosharing.TIMELINEACTIVITY");
        openMainActivity.clone();
        startActivity(openMainActivity);

    }

    if (receivedMessage.equals("unmatched")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Password or username incorrect.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

}
```

This is my Async-Task class which receives Data from my Java-Server, and checks if it was an successful or an unmatched login. In onPostExecute im calling a Method in the LoginPage.class, which handles the Intent (here comes the Error).

```
public class ConnectToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    public Context myCtx;
    static Socket socket;
    String sendStringToServer;
    int protocolId = 0;
    private static DataOutputStream DOS;
    private static DataInputStream DIS;
    StringBuffer line;
    int j = 1;
    String value;
    static String res = null;

public ConnectToServer(String sendStringToServer) {
    this.sendStringToServer = sendStringToServer;
}

public ConnectToServer(int i) {
    this.protocolId = i;
}

public ConnectToServer() {

}

public ConnectToServer(Context ctx) {
    this.myCtx = ctx;
}

protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    try {
        socket = new Socket("192.168.1.106", 25578);
        DOS = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        if (protocolId == 1) {
            DOS.writeUTF("pictureload");
            protocolId = 0;

        } else {
            DOS.writeUTF(sendStringToServer);

        }

        res = receive();
        // DOS.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("RES: " + res);

    return res;
}

public String receive() {
    String receiveResult = null;

    if (socket.isConnected()) {

        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            DIS = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            int msg_received = DIS.readInt();

            System.out.println("SERVER: " + msg_received);

            if (msg_received == 1) {
                receiveResult = "success";
                System.out.println("IF (success):   " + receiveResult);

            }

            if (msg_received == 0) {
                receiveResult = "unmatched";
                System.out.println("ELSE IF (unmatched):    "
                        + receiveResult);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // ***** return your accumulated StringBuffer as string, not current
    // line.toString();
    return receiveResult;

}

protected void onPostExecute(String result1) {

    if (result1 != null) {
        if (result1.equals("success") || result1.equals("unmatched")) {
            sendToLoginPage(result1);
        }
    }
}

private void sendToLoginPage(String result1) {
    System.out.println("sendtologi " + result1);
    LoginPage lp = new LoginPage();
    lp.getLoginMessage(result1);
}

}
```

This is the class I want to start when it was a successful login. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));        
    actionbar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#91d100")));

    ActionBar.Tab Frag1Tab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Home");
    ActionBar.Tab Frag2Tab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Share Photo");

    Fragment Fragment1 = new TimelineActivity();
    Fragment Fragment2 = new CameraActivity();

    Frag1Tab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(Fragment1));
    Frag2Tab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(Fragment2));

    actionbar.addTab(Frag1Tab);
    actionbar.addTab(Frag2Tab); 
}
}
```

Comment: Could you include the full stack trace?

Comment: You simply can't create your own `LoginPage` objects by calling the Activity constructor. Android calls it for you. All you have to do is simply implement callbacks. You need to do a bit of reading on activities and fragments ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just create instance of your `activity` with `new` keyword, like this:

```
private void sendToLoginPage(String result1) {
    System.out.println("sendtologi " + result1);
    LoginPage lp = new LoginPage();
    lp.getLoginMessage(result1);
}
```

**This is wrong** and it is probably why you are getting error. Code you posted is quite complex, so i am not sure if there are any other problems.

**This is how it should be done:**

So... Since you probably have `ConnectToServer` asyncTask in separate file, you need pass events or data to your `LoginPage` activity. For this purpose, you should use event listener, like this:

First, create interface that will represent communication between your `ConnectToServer` and your `LoginPage`.

```
public interface LoginResultListener {
  public void getLoginMessage(String receivedMessage);
}
```

Now, make your `LoginPage` `activity` implement this `interface`:

```
public class LoginPage extends Activity implements LoginResultListener {
...
}
```

Now, update your `ConnectToServer` asyncTask, so that it uses `LoginResultListener` to communicate login result to your activity, like this:

```
public class ConnectToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

  private LoginResultListener listener;
...
  public void setListener(LoginResultListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
  }
...
  private void sendToLoginPage(String result1) {
    System.out.println("sendtologi " + result1);
    //THIS IS WHERE YOU DID WRONG
    listener.getLoginMessage(result1);
  }
...
}
```

Now finally, when you create `new ConnectToServer` `async task` from your activity, you need to set listener that will handle events when user logs in. Since you implemented this interface in your activity, you will send your activity object as listener parameter, see below:

```
ConnectToServer cts = new ConnectToServer(sendProtocolToServer);
// THIS IS IMPORTANT PART - 'this' refers to your LoginPage activity, that implements LoginResultListener interface
cts.setListener(this);
cts.execute();
```

Comment: The method above is sending the data to LoginPage correctly. But if i try to start the Intent it fails. Can you please make a suggest how to do it right?

Comment: What do you mean by 'method above'? If you mean code you posted, believe me, that it DOES NOT send data to LoginPage correctly :)